# transforming uniform to exponential distribution

Tags: regression

How can I transform uniform to exponential distribution ? can i use these two formulas below ?

$$Z_1=(-2\log(U_1))^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot \cos(2\pi U_2)$$
$$Z_2=(-2\log(U_1))^\frac{1}{2}\cdot \sin(2\pi U_2)$$
Please i need some help.

Comment: Please explain what role this might have in "nonlinear regression." Could you clarify why you are calling a method of generating *Normal* random variables an "exponential transformation"?

Comment: What i mean is that i want to use box-muller to transform uniform to exponential, For random variables that follow the exponential distribution with more than one parameter.

Comment: Box-Mueller doesn't do that, so asking your question in this form is a little like asking how to use a bicycle to paddle down a river: because it makes no sense, we can't tell whether you want to bicycle or to travel along a river.

Comment: thank you i get your point, I appreciate your answer thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the density of a univariate continuous random variable $X$ into each by the following transform
$$\mathcal F_2^{-1}\left(\mathcal F_1(X)\right),$$
where $\mathcal F_1$ and $\mathcal F_2$ are the cumulative distribution functions of your source density and your target density, respectively.

In your example, $\mathcal F_1$ is the c.d.f. of the uniform distribution on an interval $[a,b]$, which is $$\mathcal F_1(x) = \frac{x-a}{b-a}.$$

The c.d.f. of an exponential distribution is $\mathcal F_2(x) = 1 − e^{-\lambda x}$ and its inverse is $$\mathcal F_2^{-1}(y) = -\frac{\log(1-y)}{\lambda}.$$ Putting it together, you get 
$$\mathcal F_2^{-1}(y) = -\frac{\log\left(1-\frac{x-a}{b-a}\right)}{\lambda}.$$

This has nothing to do with the Box-Muller transform that transforms uniform random variables on $[0,1]$ into a two-dimensional isotropic Gaussian.

Comment: You are welcome. I didn't check it numerically. So better do that.

Comment: Another thing: I apparently guessed the intention of your question correctly. However, I agree with @whuber that the question is still confusing. Could you please change the question to make it clearer. I.e. the nonlinear regression does not seem to be important and the Box-Muller transform is not applicable in this case. It would be nice to have everything clean and tidy so others can profit from your question as well. Thanks.

Comment: Ok i will try to change it, thank you so much for your help.